# Placing define macro between two string literals

Tags: c, macros, string-literals

I know it's possible to concatenate a defined macro with a string literal like so

```
#define R "car"
const char * s1 = "foo"R; //s1="foocar"
```

But when I try to place `R` between two string literals like this

```
#define R "car"
const char * s1 = "foo"R"bar"; //compile-time error
```

I get a compile time error `error: stray 'R' in program`. How can the above second example be achieved so that `s1 = "foocarbar"`?

Comment: It seems to work: https://ideone.com/7KMByV Can you add some information about the compiler and OS to reproduce the error?

Comment: Did you also get "error: invalid new-line in raw string delimiter"?

Answer (score 4):

C++ has a feature called "raw string literals", introduced by the letter `R`.

gcc apparently supports C++-style raw string literals in C as an extension. If you had used a name other than `R` for your macro, you wouldn't have had this problem.

String literal concatenation doesn't require the string literals to be adjacent. Rather than this:

```
#define R "car"
const char * s1 = "foo"R"bar";
```

you can write:

```
#define R "car"
const char * s1 = "foo" R "bar";
```

But your original code is valid C, and gcc should accept it if you use an option such as `-std=c11` to make gcc more nearly conforming.

Note that you wouldn't have had a problem if you had used a name other than `R` for your macro.

Comment: What version of C++ introduced this feature?